# keyframes from videofile - how to do fast extract in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, opencv3.0

I know ffmpeg can do this from command line and almost sure it can do this from C++ code too. But is there any simple way in C++ OpenCV3 or OpenCV2 to grab from videofile  keyframes only?

[Before](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1419) `video.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` worked this way: position was "nearest keyframe", but now it is "fixed" and I can not find the way how to process keyframes only (for perfomance purpose) at least in one possible way:

- 1st way : `read()` next **key**frame (like JavaCV `FFmpegFrameGrabber.grabKeyFrame()` )
- 2nd way: do fast-working `grab()` for **each** frame, check it's propertie (which one?) and if it is keyframe then do slow-working `retrieve()` .